# Why the output of lsblk have almost the same lines?

Tags: lsblk

```
lsblk -d -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE | grep disk
```

show me the such things

```
sda  894.3G disk
sdb  894.3G disk
sdc    3.7T disk
sdd    3.7T disk
nbd0    64G disk
```

Are the `sda` and `sdc` have `sdb` and `sdd` similarly physical devices?
Either they're "physical" and "logical" devices?

It's not my own server, so I cannot see its specifications. The server was deployed without  my participation.

Comment: What makes you think there is an issue here? I mean, what is it that seems strange?

Comment: I cannot understand why are they exactly the same disk pairs. Are they separate 4 physical disks?
It's one of the on-support servers, and I have never seem such things at another servers.

Comment: @terdon hm. I've used `hdparm` and saw there're two separate disks of one model with different Serial Number`s.

Comment: @terdon I posted answer below.

Comment: Possibly two logical devices set up as two mirrors of two disks each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those are 5 separate disks. You have 4 disks connected via the SCSI interface (sda, sdb, sdc and sdd). You also have one network block device, a physical disk on a remote machine that has been made available to your machine over [NBD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_block_device).

This is quite a normal setup (apart from the NBD which isn't very common these days). You very often have similar disks on a server since the server's administrator would have bought a few together and since having disks of the same size makes setting up RAID systems is much simpler. It isn't strange or surprising.

You can investigate further using `parted -l` which will will show the model and make of the disks. Or you can use more general commands for hardware information like `lshw` or `hwinfo`.

Comment: Those pairs are also likely in some form of RAID1/mirror configuration for redundancy whether that's with mdadm/lvm/zfs/btrfs... `lsblk` without options may tell the OP more.

Comment: Ah yes, good point @StéphaneChazelas, I added a note about RAID.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `hdparm` util and check info about `sda` and `sdb` disks.
They're disks of one model, but every of them have separate Serial Number.
So they're separate but similar physical devices.